# Git branch management

Tags: git, branch

Can anyone help me on the below question?

Currently, I modified some code in master branch locally. Then, I need to commit and push that changes to a new branch(newly created branch). How can I do it?

Comment: Hi, you may checkout and create the new branch by "git checkout -b namenewbranch". After that add and commit your changes to that branch. "git status" and then push to a new remote branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's not committed yet do:

- `git stash`
- `git checkout -b new-branch-name`
- on your new branch do `git stash apply`

  THEN commit and push

if it's already committed then I think this could work

- do `git log`
- get the commit hash ex: `0a8066e5fdcb0ce71dc1cb22c7cafd05d3cd7577`
- go to the new branch by `git checkout -b new-branch-name develop` (make sure you don't branch out of master)
- on your current branch do `git cherry-pick 0a8066e5fdcb0ce71dc1cb22c7cafd05d3cd7577`

Answer (score 2):

```sh
git checkout -b <branch name>
git commit -am "your commit message"
git push -u origin <branch name>
```